# How to solve this type of permutations product question

Tags: abstract-algebra

$a=(3,1,2,4,5),\, b=(2,1,4,3)$. Find ab

a has more elements than b so how do i do it so far I have:

$ab=(1,5$ 
But i dont know where to go from $5$ i cant close the bracket since its not a cycle but theres no '$5$'s in $b$.

Answer (score 2):

In this notation, numbers not mentioned are fixed.

So, if p = (1,3,2), then p sends 1 to 3, 3 to 2, 2 to 1, 4 to 4, 5 to 5, 6 to 6, 7 to 7, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Permutation is a $1-1$ and onto function.
 
So if you are in $X_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$, then $b:X_n\rightarrow X_n$ is a $1-1$ and onto function. We can say same things for $a$.
$ab$ means $a\circ b$.
 (Sometimes can be be ragarded $b\circ a$)
For example $a\circ b(1)=a(4)=5$
You wrote $5\not \in b$. This is not meaningful. Because of $b$ is a function. You mean $5$ has no image under $b$. But this is a contradiction of $b$ is onto( or $1-1$  $X_n$ is a finite set)

 Think $(1)=(2)=(3)=(4)=...=(n)$. All of them are equal and identity.
Finally,Conclude that $b(5)=?$, $b(6)=?$,..., $b(n)=?$